# SQL SELECT avg of columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-quicksight

I have a SQL query now that produces a table that looks like this:

| Demographic | Month | Week | Usability | Session |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | 5 | 7 | 9 |

This is the query:

```
SELECT

    avg(cast(d.duration as bigint)) as "Demographic",
    avg(cast(m.duration as bigint)) as "Month",
    avg(cast(w.duration as bigint)) as "Week",
    avg(cast(u.duration as bigint)) as "Usability",
    avg(cast(s.duration as bigint)) as "Session"
   
FROM 
    "demographic" as d,
    "month" as m,
    "week" as w,
    "usability" as u,
    "session" as s
```

What I want is a table that looks like this:

| Table | Average Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Demographic | 2 |
| Month | 10 |
| Week | 5 |
| Usability | 7 |
| Session | 9 |

Is this possible?

Comment: You are aware that the query you've shown us here creates a cartesian product?

Comment: `d.info.duration` isn't a valid column reference.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION` to get each result on a different row.

```
SELECT 'Demographic' AS Table, AVG(CAST(duration) AS BIGINT) AS `Average Duration` FROM demographic
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Month', AVG(CAST(duration) AS BIGINT) FROM month
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Week', AVG(CAST(duration) AS BIGINT) FROM week
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Usability', AVG(CAST(duration) AS BIGINT) FROM usability
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Session', AVG(CAST(duration) AS BIGINT) FROM session
```